# Mysql saving file as blob, result is much bigger than actual filesize

Tags: mysql, pdf, blob

I have an issue, when I upload my pdf file as a longblob to my database the file is much bigger than expected.
The original file is abut 430kb and my blob turns out to be 91mb. The procedure I have is working on most files. but this one fails. I have tried to delete the pdf and reproduce it, still gives the same result. any ideas?

Comment: How did you acertain that the original file is only 430KB?

Comment: printed email via print to pdf in windows 10